# List Indexing and Reverse Indexing

Tags: python, list, indexing

## Python and Indexing

I've been working on a vanilla Python code to separate data from a csv.  My goal is to recreate this code using multiple strategies in order to better my understanding of Python.  Improvements to this code will come later.  The code I have works, but there are a couple things that I don't understand.  Here it is:

```
with open('C:\My Super Secret Path\primary_debates_cleaned.csv') as primaryData:
    headers = primaryData.readline().strip('\n').split(',')

    flag = 0
    for lines in primaryData:
        sepInit = lines.strip('\n').split('"')

        if flag == 1:
            sep1 = [item for item in sepInit[0].split(',') if item is not '']
            sep2 = sepInit[1]
            sep3 = [item for item in sepInit[2].split(',') if item is not '']

            #sep4 = sepInit[3]
            sep4 = sepInit[-2]

            #sep5 = sepInit[4].strip(',')
            sep5 = sepInit[-1].strip(',')

            #sepFinal = [sep1[0], sep1[1], sep2, sep3[0], sep3[1], sep4, sep5]
            sepFinal = [sep1[0], sep1[1], sep2, sep3[0:1], sep3[1:2], sep4, sep5]

        if flag == 0:
            sepFinal = headers
            flag = 1

print sepFinal
```

My first question concerns this snippet, specifically indexing:

```
#sep4 = sepInit[3]
sep4 = sepInit[-2]

#sep5 = sepInit[4].strip(',')
sep5 = sepInit[-1].strip(',')
```

The commented part is what I want to do, and the uncommented part is what works.  It seems like I have to reverse the index in order to grab the proper information.  The "type" seems to be the same, both being lists.  Is there something I'm doing incorrectly at the start, or am I missing something simple here?

My next question has a similar flavor, from the snippet below:

```
#sepFinal = [sep1[0], sep1[1], sep2, sep3[0], sep3[1], sep4, sep5]
sepFinal = [sep1[0], sep1[1], sep2, sep3[0:1], sep3[1:2], sep4, sep5]
```

Why is it that I can get the information I need from `sep1` simply using 0 and 1, but I cannot do the same for `sep3`?

Finally, when printing out the list `sepFinal`, the elements for `sep4` and `sep5` appear as lists.  Everything else is just an element of the list `sepFinal`, but `sep4` and `sep5` are lists within the list.  If this needs clarification, let me know.  So, why do `sep4` and `sep5` appear as lists within my list?

EDIT0: There are no inputs to this.  I am going into the PowerShell, and typing `python mySecretProgramName.py` to run it. The `print sepFinal` shows the following, parenthesized:

```
>>> [element 1, element 2, element 3, [element 4], [element 5]]
```

From the start, I'd like it to be:

```
>>> [element 1, element 2, element 3, element 4, element 5]
```

EDIT1: The negative indexing was needed due to data being improperly split.  The length of `sepInit` was changing, so the indexing was not correct.  Thank you to @martineau for pointing out this possibility.  I tested this by simply putting `print(len(sepInit))` after `sepInit` in the loop.

Negative indexing information: `someList[-1]` grabs the last item in a list, `someList[-2]` grabs the second to last item in a list, etc.

EDIT2: This concerns `sep3[0:1]` and the like.  This essentially takes slice of the list, where `sep3[0:1]` would return whatever element falls between the places 0 and 1.

Comment: Please provide a small example of inputs and the results of your commented lines that are producing unexpected outputs

Comment: Hey @TheoretiCAL, see the edit please.

Comment: It's a CSV file, but you're splitting on `"`? Why? When @TheoretiCAL asked for your input, we need to see `primary_debates_cleaned.csv`

Comment: This is kind of outside of the scope of my questions.  I'm doing multiple splits because there are commas between "s, and I'm just playing around with different ways to use python and mess with data.

EDIT: I understand there are easier ways to do this - I want to know more about indexing lists, and why certain elements are showing up as a list within a list.  Do you have an answer for that?

Comment: The answer to your first sub-question is simple. The list has a length different from what you expect, which is causing the "reverse" indexing to not give you the value you want. Also your script _does_ have input, namely the .csv file it reads. So we still don't know what the input looks like.

Comment: @martineau - You are correct that the list does vary in length, which is causing the issue!  Thank you for answering my first question.  I'm new, how do I give you credit?

Comment: You're welcome. I suppose you could upvote my comment, however it's not very important.